# Factory reset Windows Server 2016 on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

I installed a few beta version of some apps and now the functionality of the Windows is broken.

Is there any way I can reset the windows to it's initial state from the portal or I have to remove it and create a new one?

Comment: If you have not backup this VM or take a snapshot of this VM, we should create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not backup this VM or take a snapshot of this VM, we should re-create a new VM.

Comment: Well, such a pity! It just happened a couple of ours after creating it. Then I will remove and create a new one. But do I need to delete the whole Resource Group or there is a way to re-create only VM?

Comment: you could delete the vm only and rerun the deployment you used to create the vm, but you would probably waste more time. just create a new one in new rg and delete old rg @Mori

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jason, if a backup or a snapshot was taken, you could use them to recover the VM.

You have mentioned, ‘now the functionality of the Windows is broken’, unsure if you are facing some boot issue or something else. Please do let me know if feasible, you could look at fixing the underlying issue. Or just recreate the problematic VM and not the entire Resource Group itself.

I would like to highlight the process of recovering the OS below:

1. Delete the VM encountering issues, keeping the virtual hard disks.
2. Attach and mount the virtual hard disk to another Windows VM for troubleshooting purposes.
3. Connect to the troubleshooting VM. Edit files or run any tools to fix issues on the original virtual hard disk.
4. Unmount and detach the virtual hard disk from the troubleshooting VM.
5. Create a VM using the original virtual hard disk.

Refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-recovery-disks-portal) for more details on this process.